# Tosfos Yom Tov editions/commentaries

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, mishna

Besides *Ikar Tosfos Yom Tov*, are there any helpful/modern editions of *Tosfos Yom Tov* that can help me learn the sefer?

Comment: The  Ikar Tosfos Yom Tov is not really a summary of the TYT - it's ALSO a summary of some TYT, but a lot of shadowing the Bartenura and filling in parts he omitted and occasionally correcting him.

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

I recently discovered - "משניות תוס' יו"ט המבואר" "ששון יו"ט". Available for several masechtos, link [here](https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1-%D7%99%D7%95%D7%98-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%95%D7%90%D7%A8-%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D).